# Batch: Move files to folder for first letter of the name?

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to have 3 folders, A-G, H-T, and U-Z. I wanted files to automatically be sorted into these folders via batch based on the first letter of the name. Any way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%a IN (*) DO (
 IF /i "%%a" geq "a" IF /i "%%a" lss "h" ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\A-G\"
 IF /i "%%a" geq "h" IF /i "%%a" lss "u" ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\H-T\"
 IF /i "%%a" geq "u" (
  IF /i "%%a" lss "z" (ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\U-Z\"
  ) ELSE (
   SET "name=%%a"
   IF /i "!name:~0,1!"=="Z" ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\U-Z\"
  )
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

The difficult part is comparing the name against (something greater than Z). Unfortunately, neither `[` nor `{` work in this position. `if` regards both `[` and `{` as lower than `A` - or even numerics...

Hence, for filenames beginning `z`, employ a specific test.

Comment: Couldn't you use `leq "z"` here?

Comment: @DennisvanGils: No. Consider "z.txt". This is greater than `z`. According to ASCII, `[` should be `Z`+1 and `{` is `z` + 1. According to `cmd`, both `{` and `[` are less than `0`...Astonishing, but true...

Comment: Some people are ungrateful. From me a +1

Comment: Some people aren't considerate of new members! +1 from me as well.