# Make folders based on first word in file name in Windows?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

i'm trying to make a batch file that will organize all files in folders based on the first word in the file names.

For example:

```
Monkey 122.jpg
Monkey 154.jpg
Monkey 652.jpg
Giraffe 433.jpg
Giraffe 456.jpg
Giraffe 883.jpg
```

Would organize into 2 folders:
Monkey
Giraffe

I have about 1500 files all with different names i'd like to organize!

Right now I'm using

```
@for %%A in (*.jpg) do @for /f %%B in ("%%A") Do mkdir %%B
```

to make folders for each file name, but can't seem to figure out how to move them into the folders

Comment: [SO] isn't a script writing service. You should [edit] your question to show your coding effort in a [mcve]. Point out where you got stuck and then you'll get the help needed.

Comment: To give you a start `@for %%A in (*.jpg) do @for /f %%B in ("%%A") Do @Echo %%B %%A`

Comment: I did mkdir instead of echo and it's making much more than the first word! I was using about 600 files and I ended up with 1500 folders or so

Comment: Okay I changed this to

Comment: I just see you didn't honour Magoo's good answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646640/batch-move-files-to-folder-for-first-letter-of-the-name) neither accepting nor upvoting it. And please read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: This is my second post brother... I'll just go elsewhere if no one will help and I just get criticized. This isn't the correct way to grow a community.

Comment: Well, I count three posts. If you can't stand justified criticism - that's your problem. If [SO] should have a growth problem I guess it's the other way around. I already gave you hints and you are free to read the detailed help of every command via `/?` or reading [ss64.com/nt](http://ss64.com/nt)

Comment: Whatever the case may be, I've obviously barely used the site. And I would say you're not treating a new member correctly. Just my input. I already figured my problem out, thanks for your help.