# Copy folders and files to a new location based on the first character of the folder or file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I wanted to have folders and files copied to a new location via batch based on the first letter of the name and keeping it's original folder structure when copied to the new location. (incremental)

Examples:

Any folder or file that begins with A-M or 0-9 copied to N:\movies

Any folder or file that begins with N-Z copied to M:\movies

I found a similar script here: [Batch: Move files to folder for first letter of the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646640/batch-move-files-to-folder-for-first-letter-of-the-name)

current code:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=N:\" 
SET "destdir=M:\" 
PUSHD "%sourcedir%" 
FOR %%a IN (*) DO ( 
 IF /i "%%a" geq "a" IF /i "%%a" lss "h" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\" 
 IF /i "%%a" geq "h" IF /i "%%a" lss "u" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\H-T\"
 IF /i "%%a" geq "u" (
  IF /i "%%a" lss "z" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\U-Z\" 
  ) ELSE (
   SET "name=%%a" 
   IF /i "!name:~0,1!"=="Z" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\U-Z\" 
  ) 
 )
) 
popd 
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? You should demonstrate that you have tried sth and it did not work and explain where the problem is so that people here can have a look at it and help you

Comment: This is what I have so far however it copies files but not folders, also it does not recognize if a file has already been copied and has not changed,

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=N:\"
SET "destdir=M:\"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%a IN (*) DO (
 IF /i "%%a" geq "a" IF /i "%%a" lss "h" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\"
 IF /i "%%a" geq "h" IF /i "%%a" lss "u" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\H-T\"
 IF /i "%%a" geq "u" (
  IF /i "%%a" lss "z" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\U-Z\"
  ) ELSE (
   SET "name=%%a"
   IF /i "!name:~0,1!"=="Z" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\U-Z\"
  )
 )
)
popd

GOTO :EOF

Comment: This is not a please write it for me community! You should demonstrate that you have written the code yourself and you understand where your problem is to get help

Comment: lbo With all due respect I do understand what I have so far, I jusy don't know how to change the copy command to include folders. Ive tried adding *.* but it still does not copy folders.

Comment: Ah - but not that you should post code by editing your question using the `edit` facility since attempting to decipher code in comments is a major pain.

Comment: Since you haven't said what the script does that it shouldn't do, not what it doesn't do what you expect, we get all the fun of guessing. Your description doesn't match the code. `for /d` is required to process directorynames, I'd suggest using `xcopy` for that phase. There is no processing for 0..9; the `\a-m` appears missing. I'd suggest your partitioning should be [lss "a"];[geq "a" lss "h"];[geq "h" lss "u"] and [geq "u"].

Comment: Magoo thanks for your reply. The script you wrote does some of what I want it to do it copies files to a specified location based on the first letter of the file name. What I need it to do is copy files and folders to a specified location based on the first letter of the file or folder name.           Examples:

Any folder or file that begins with A-M or 0-9 copied to N:\movies

Any folder or file that begins with N-Z copied to M:\movies